# Why is the total number of heads a sufficient statistic for a Bernoulli variable?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Learning about sufficient statistics my text has the following example that I don't understand:

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$. Then
>   $\mathcal{L}(p) = p^S(1-p)^{n-S}$ where $S = \sum_i X_i$, so $S$ is
>   sufficient.

Intuitively I understand a statistic being sufficient to mean that if I know it I should be able to calculate the likelihood function without knowing the actual value of the parameter $p$. But I don't see how that's the case here -- knowing $S$ and $n$ isn't enough, I still need $p$ and $(1-p)$ to compute the function, or don't I?

Comment: Do you know *Factorisation theorem*? Or how do you prove that a statistic is sufficient from definition?

Comment: @StubbornAtom the chapter appendix also covers the Factorization Theorem, but that's later and optional so I suspect it's somehow supposed to be obvious without it.

Comment: Sufficiency of $S$ can be formally proved by showing that the conditional distribution $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\mid S$ is independent of $p$.